# SelectMany not supported in RavenDB Reduce expression?

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, ravendb

I have a scenario where I want to store small documents in batches, because of insert performance. But of course I want to be able to search the individual items.

```
public class Batch
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I want to search by Description and that I want the IDs to be returned. I created the following very simple map/reduce index which I would expect to do just that:

```
Map = batches =>
    from batch in batches
    from item in batch.Items
    select new Result
        {
             Description = item.Description,
             ItemIds = new[] {item.Id}
        };

Reduce = results =>
    from result in results
    group result by result.Description into g
    select new Result
        {
             Description = g.Key,
             ItemIds = g.SelectMany(x => x.ItemIds).ToArray()
        };
```

A query using this index does not fail, it just does not return any results.

If the index is modified just a little, to use string.Join instead of SelectMany to get the IDs, everything works fine.

```
Map = batches =>
     from batch in batches
     from item in batch.Items
     select new Result
         {
             Description = item.Description,
             ItemIdsAsString = item.Id.ToString(),
         };

Reduce = results =>
     from result in results
     group result by result.Description into g
     select new Result
         {
             Description = g.Key,
             ItemIdsAsString = string.Join("|", g.Select(x => x.ItemIdsAsString)),
         };
```

The behavior is completely the same, only that the IDs are now stored as "2|5|7" instead of as an array of these integers. But this time, the index produces the correct results.

[A full test can be found here](https://gist.github.com/3690005)

Is there a reason why SelectMany doesn't work in the Reduce expression?

Comment: Is it related to this: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-297?

Comment: Hmm, prohibiting SelectMany in the index definition seems to be very restrictive.
The workaround with the string.Join is not very nice, but it does work. Anybody got a nicer solution to search for children in a set of documents? Seems to be a very widely applicable scenario...

Comment: By the way, solved the issue with the insert performance by batching the inserts themselves (not inserting batch documents anymore). No need for SelectMany anymore.